# how to optimize queries in magento 1.9 with lots of attributes (over 500)

Tags: magento-1.9, query, optimization

I have a website running Magento 1.9 which is flooding mysql with slow queries like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2' WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(78661, 78664, 78668, 78659, 78660, 78658, 78657, 78656, ...about 1000 more ids)
```

I'm assuming this has to do with caregory and layered navigation so I disabled the layered navigation counts globally. It helped mitigate the problem but it's still not quite solved so I want to takle it at the source.

Could someone help me understand when these queries are run and why this is happening?

Another example

```
SELECT `trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx`.`value`, COUNT(trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx.entity_id) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx` ON trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx.entity_id = e.entity_id AND trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx.attribute_id = '321' AND trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx.store_id = '1' WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(78661, 78664, ...more ids)
GROUP BY `trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx`
```

They seem to be fairly common in all magento 1.9 running instances and connected to the layered navigation and pagination.

Is there something I could change on mysql server to improve this?
Is this behaviour something documented in Magento 1.9?

PS: Due to the amount of attributes I can't enable flat catalog because it hits the max row limit in mysql.

Comment: trofodosia_boyrtsas, is there some kind of custom module / third party module that works with those query? I've never seen anything like: "trofodosia_boyrtsas_idx"

Comment: This is just an attribute that probably gets indexed by amasty improved layered navigation.

Comment: However I think I found the root cause is not within Magento but with the underlying MariaDB Server, it seems in 10.2.35-bionic it has a bug which causes it to slow down queries with a lot of IN clauses. I'm currently investigating this path futher

Comment: Happened to me that i had to remove as much as i can in one project the amount of queries that had an IN inside them, with a catalog of more than 50k / 100k products those queries kills the DB

Comment: Please consider posting EXPLAIN SELECT .....; for your slow query and SHOW CREATE TABLE (tbl_name); for each table referenced.  It is likely you have unnecessary quotes around numeric search values, leading to time wasted on datatype manipulation.

Comment: @WilsonHauck It turned out it was a bug in MariaDB that could be reproduced outside of Magento as well as I posted on my answer. Any query with lots of values in an IN Clause caused tremendous slowness in MariaDB 10.2 , the other versions are not affected. Also it was the ubuntu version of MariaDB not the original

Comment: Can you describe the corrective action to avoid the tremendous slowness?

Comment: The corrective action was to upgrade to Maria DB 10.3. Unfortunately nothing you can do in code will improve it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution.

Comment: No problem, I had already added it in my own answer but I forgot to accept it :)

Comment: This is an issue I have with an instance and I note your comment regarding MariaDB versions. I have had this problem using 10.1.48... I am wondering about your use of Amasty Improved Navigation, as we also have this installed, suspect this is the culprit... Also you wouldn't happen to have Smartwave Ajax Catalouge Installed? There is a known issue here - might be unrelated.

Comment: Yes we have amasty improved layered navigation but even disabling it didn't help at all. Also sites without the module were affected as well. As long as the query had a lot of values in the in clause it was struggling

Comment: Try the query I added in pastebin and see if it takes more than 100ms. If it does you have the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else searches for the same issue apparently it's a bug in mysql 5.6 and affects mariadb 10.2.35-bionic as well. When you have many static values in an IN() clause like magento does for categories and layered navigation it will cause extreme stress on the mysql server calculating the statistics to optimize the query.

I've tested the same query using different Maria DB versions

- 10.2.36 (0.058sec)
- 10.2.35-bionic (72sec)
- 10.3.26-bionic (0.27sec)
- 10.5.x (0.53sec)

And only 10.2.35-bionic was affected using docker containers.

To test if you're affected you can run the following test which was found in MySQL bugtracker (linking to pastebin because it's too big for an answer)

https://pastebin.com/x9AziWXF

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize query on Product Description Page try to remove inner join with associated product which makes a lot difference to load product data.